# SQL error key column does not exist when importing into EC2

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I'm building an SQL database in PHPMyAdmin and importing it into SQL Server on EC2.  When I import the database I get an error saying:

> ERROR 1072 (42000) at line 119: Key column 'des_code_lot' doesn't exist in table

I went to line 119 and found:

```
ALTER TABLE lot
ADD CONSTRAINT des_code_lot FOREIGN KEY (des_code_lot) REFERENCES destination (des_code);`
```

Earlier in the SQL code I had:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lot ( des_code_lot int(11) NOT NULL,
...
```

I thought this created the column in the table lot.

I already have the tables on InnoDB.

Is there anyway I can get around this in phpmyadmin?

Also, is there an easier way to set up a SQL database on EC2 that involves foreign keys without having to export/import SQL files?

Comment: The constraint and the column are named the same??

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the constraint was not added since there is already a column with that name.

Change this:
`ALTER TABLE lot ADD CONSTRAINT des_code_lot FOREIGN KEY (des_code_lot) REFERENCES destination (des_code);`

To this:
`ALTER TABLE lot ADD CONSTRAINT fk_des_code_lot FOREIGN KEY (des_code_lot) REFERENCES destination (des_code);`

Comment: Just added '_constraint' to all of my constraints, and the message is still there.